# Store an output randomly printed from a list as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, output

So I'm trying to make a program that randomly prints out a series of random letters.

But my letter_combo in the user input shows only the last set from the original randomized version

```
import random
list = ['AB','CD','GF','HD',]
for x in range(3):
    letter_combo = random.choice(list)
    print(letter_combo,end='') 
print('\t')
user_answr = input("Rewrite for " + str(letter_combo)+ ": ")
if user_answr == letter_combo:
    print("Good")
elif user_answr !=letter_combo:
    print("Wrong combination")
```

here's the output

```
ABCDGF
Rewrite for GF:
```

every thing else seems fine. I just want to keep the whole initial line (ABCDGF) and have the user verify that it's correct, is there anyway to store it maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.sample) to make a selection of 3 words from the list, and then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them to make your letter combo:

```py
letter_combo = ''.join(random.sample(list, k=3))
```

Sample output:

```
CDGFAB
```

Note, if you want to allow repetition in the output, use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.choices) instead:

```
letter_combo = ''.join(random.choices(list, k=3))
```

Sample output:

```
HDHDAB
```